# Who is the author ע״ש quoted by באר היטב?

Tags: shulchan-aruch, acronyms

The באר היטב in חושן משפט quotes a posek ע״ש (not עיין שם). For example, ס׳ מ״ב ס׳ק ז:

> כגון.  כתב **הע"ש** אבל אם כתב ר"ת כגון י"ב י"ג כשר שא"א לזייף וליכא למיחש
> שמא הי' כתוב ב' או ג' והוסיף היו"ד דחזק' על העדים שעשו כהוגן ואם הי'
> כתוב בו ב' או ג' לא היו חותמין ע"כ ולא דק דלמה לא יכתוב ג' דהא ליכא
> לזייף ולעשות ממנה אות אחר עכ"ל הסמ"ע וכתב הש"ך דאין זו השג' דהא יש
> לעשות מן ג' נ' בכתב אשורית ע' בתשובת מהר"מ איסרלש סי' ע"ד ובמבי"ט ח"א
> בשאלות השניות סי' קנ"ה עכ"ל (וכ"כ הט"ז):‏

[https://www.sefaria.org/Ba'er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.42.7](https://www.sefaria.org/Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.42.7)

Who is that?

Comment: I would assume it is the לבוש. The חלק on חושן משפט is called עיר שושן.

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. Quoted here in Sif Daled:
https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9275&st=&pgnum=35&hilite=
If you write an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: עולת שבת?......

Comment: @kouty that is usually the case in OC, but not in CM.

Comment: Oups, I didn't notice that the question was about Choshen Mishpat @Bach

Comment: Possibly Sefer Amudei Shlomo by Rabbi Shlomo Yechiel Luria. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Luria  And also  https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=22254#p=1&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=

Answer (score 1):

It is the לבוש.

The חלק on חושן משפט is called עיר שושן.

[See here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9275&st=&pgnum=35&hilite=)